# Bluetooth Handler in Android - Run only once

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

Hi I want to make two of my **Case statements to run only once**. How do I make the `PLAYER_GAMEPIECE_WRITE` and `PLAYER_GAMEPIECE_READ` Case statements to run only once just like the `MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME` case? They just seem to loop through each other. It does not proceed to the next case.

Handler code:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(final Message msg)
    {
        switch (msg.what)
        {

            // If the two devices are connected
            case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);

                Toast.makeText(TwoPlayerActivityBluetooth.this, "Connected to " + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            case PLAYER_GAMEPIECE_WRITE:
                //INSERT CODE HERE
                break;

            case PLAYER_GAMEPIECE_READ:
                //INSERT CODE HERE
                break;

            case PLAYER_LOCATION_WRITE:
                //INSERT CODE HERE
                break;

            case PLAYER_LOCATION_READ:
                //INSERT CODE HERE 
                break;
```

BluetoothService code:

```
public void run()
        {
            readGamepiece();
            readLocation();
        }

public void readGamepiece()
    {

        byte[] buffer2 = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                bytes = mInStream.read(buffer2);
 mHandler.obtainMessage(TwoPlayerActivityBluetooth.PLAYER_GAMEPIECE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer2).sendToTarget();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    public void writeGamepiece(byte[] buffer2)
    {
        try
        {
            mOutStream.write(buffer2);
mHandler.obtainMessage(TwoPlayerActivityBluetooth.PLAYER_GAMEPIECE_WRITE, -1 , -1 , buffer2).sendToTarget();

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }


    public void readLocation()
    {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                bytes = mInStream.read(buffer);
                mHandler.obtainMessage(TwoPlayerActivityBluetooth.PLAYER_LOCATION_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    public void writeLocation(byte[] buffer)
    {
        try
        {
            mOutStream.write(buffer);
            mHandler.obtainMessage(TwoPlayerActivityBluetooth.PLAYER_LOCATION_WRITE, -1 , -1 , buffer).sendToTarget();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You actually never exit the `readGamepiece` method unless bt connection is lost, I'm pretty sure. That's what the `while(true) {}` means. You will have to rethink what you want to do, but infinite loop is not the solution.

Comment: Oh, that's a bummer. What I want to do is to send/receive data the moment the two devices are connected. The data that will be sent/received will determine what type of game board will be displayed. Can you give me an idea on how to do that? Thank you so much

Comment: You could consider making a loop outside of the two `read(Gamepiece|Location)` methods and have just a single read in each one of them. Precisely how to do that depends on what is in the input stream: both of your reads seem to be on the same data connection, but you somehow differentiate them into separate events. Also, maybe make another way to stop the loop other than connection loss, for other inapp purposes (but that depends on whether you have any other purposes to begin with).

Comment: The readGamepiece and the writeGamepiece is for the data that will determine what type of game board will be displayed. While the readLocation and writeLocation is for the exchange of data (game pieces and their location) in the game itself.

Comment: Then to me this sounds like there should be no loop at all in `readGamepiece`, because type of board is determined once per session (I assume). To shorten this discussion: think how your communication is done in principle, overall. Write it out on paper if you like. Then convert to the code. If your principal schema includes any "when"s at all, then you actually will have no loops, only request-response stuff, event style. You also possibly need service bytes in communication, designating the type of your event being transmitted.

Comment: Sorry, I am just a newbie in programming. How do I not include the `readGamepiece` in the loop? Thank you